# What is the soul of the LORD?

Tags: leviticus

English Standard Version

> Leviticus 25:1
> The LORD spoke to Moses on Mount Sinai, saying
> ...
> 26:30
> And I will destroy your high places and cut down your incense altars and cast your dead bodies upon the dead bodies of your idols, and **my soul** will abhor you.

What is the soul of the LORD?

Comment: Is it not the same **soul** that *delights in [his] servant* in Isaiah 42:1? (Seems like there is a more fitting tag)

Comment: The study of the word _nephesh_ needs to be extensive to indicate its broad meaning and that it does not (and cannot) mean 'soul' in the way that humans have a soul. 'Depths' is as close as I can achieve. My own study of the word is too extensive to duplicate here. But an excellent question, up-voted +1.

Answer (score 2):

The Hebrew word נֶפֶשׁ (nephesh = "soul") has a very broad meaning and widely used idiom.  A glance at BDB or any other lexicon shows this quite dramatically - the entry for this word will be very long.  Actually, the meaning in Hebrew is not all that far from the broad meaning of "soul" in English - People talk about "the inmost soul" meaning inner feelings etc.

For example, NAS suggests its meaning encompasses, "a soul, living being, life, self, person, desire, passion, appetite, emotion."

BDB summary has: "soul, living being, life, self, person, desire, appetite, emotion, and passion."

**PART** of the entry in BDB says this:

> paraphrase for personal pronoun especially in poetry and ornate
> discourse, 70 t.; (1) נַפְשִׁי = me: אל תבא נפשׁי Genesis 49:6 let me
> not enter (poem in J); מות ישׁרים ׳תָּמֹת נ Numbers 23:10 let me die,
> etc. (poem); תָּמוֺת נַפְשְׁי Judges 16:30 (J); אמרה נפשׁי
> Lamentations 3:24 I say. (2) נַפְשְׁךָ = thee: לְאֻמִּים תַּחַת
> נַפְשֶׁ֑ךָ Isaiah 43:4 peoples instead of thee; אָֽמְרוּ לְנַפְשֵׁךְ
> Isaiah 51:23. (3) נַפְשׁוֺ = he: נפשׁו בטוב תלין Psalms he will not
> dwell in good circumstances. (4) נַפְשֵׁנוּ = we: נַפְשֵׁנוּ
> כְּצִמּוֺר נִמְלְטָה מִמַּח יוֺקְשִׁים Psalm 124:7. (5) נַפְשָׁם =
> they, them: נַפְשָׁם בַּשְּׁבִי הָלָ֑כָה Isaiah 46:2 they are gone
> into captivity; אוי לנפשׁם Isaiah 3:9.

Further, as part of the idiom of inner feelings and deep passion, we also have the followings meanings:

> 6 = ׳נ seat of emotions and passions (151 t.) —
>
> **a. desire**: ׳אִוְּתָה נ soul desires Deuteronomy 12:20; Deuteronomy
> 14:26; 1 Samuel 2:16; 2 Samuel 3:21; 1 Kings 11:37; Job 23:13;
> Proverbs 13:4; Proverbs 21:10; Micah 7:1; ׳תַּאֲוַת נ Psalm 10:3;
> Isaiah 26:8; ׳אַוַּת נ Deuteronomy 12:15,20,21; Deuteronomy 18:6; 1
> Samuel 23:20; Jeremiah 2:24; so also לנפשׁ according to one's desire
> Deuteronomy 21:14; Psalm 78:18; Jeremiah 34:16; כנפשׁ Deuteronomy
> 23:25; האח נפשׁנו ah, our desire Psalm 35:25; בנפשׁ at one's desire
> Psalm 105:22; Ezekiel 16:27; יָָֽצְאָה ׳נ בְדַבְּרוֺ Songs 5:6; ׳נשׂא
> נ lift up the soul, desire Deuteronomy 24:15; 2 Samuel 14:14 (read
> אליהם, not אלהים), Psalm 24:4; Psalm 25:1; Psalm 86:4; Psalm 143:8;
> Proverbs 19:8; Jeremiah 22:27; Jeremiah 44:14; Hosea 4:8.
>
> **b. abhorrence, loathing**: ׳געלה נ soul abhorreth Leviticus
> 26:11,15,30,43 (H) Jeremiah 14:19; בחלה בי ׳וגם נ Zechariah 11:8 and
> their soul also fell a loathing against me.
>
> **c. sorrow and distress**: ׳מרי נ bitter, gloomy, discontented of soul
> Judges 18:25 (E) 2 Samuel 17:8; Job 3:20; Proverbs 31:6; ׳מר נ 1
> Samuel 22:2 compare Job 7:11; Job 10:1; Isaiah 38:15; Ezekiel 27:1;
> ׳עָֽגְמָה נ Job 30:35 grieved; ׳אגמי נ sad of soul Isaiah 19:10; ׳תבכה
> נ my soul shall weep Jeremiah 13:17; ירעה ׳נ his soul trembleth Isaiah
> 15:4; ׳צרת נ distress of soul Genesis 42:21 (E).
>
> **d. joy**: תגיל ׳נ my soul rejoiceth Psalm 35:9; Isaiah 61:10; ׳שׂמּח נ
> rejoice the soul Psalm 86:4; also Psalm 94:19; Psalm 138:3; Proverbs
> 29:17.
>
> **e. love**: ׳אהבה נ my soul loveth Songs 1:7; Songs 3:1,2,3,4; ׳יְדִדוּת
> נ darling of my soul Jeremiah 12:7; ׳ב ׳דבקה נ his soul clave unto
> Genesis 34:3 (J), with אחרי Psalm 63:9; חשׁקה ׳ב ׳נ soul is attached
> to Genesis 34:8 (P).
>
> **f. alienation, hatred, revenge**: מן ׳תֵּקַע נ the soul is alienated
> from Jeremiah 6:8; Ezekiel 23:17,18; מן ׳נקעה נ Ezekiel 23:18,22,28;
> ׳שְׂנֻאי נ hated of soul 2 Samuel 5:8 (Qr); ׳שׂנאה נ Psalm 11:5;
> Isaiah 1:14.
>
> **g. other emotions and feelings**: ׳השׁיב נ bring back soul Lamentations
> 1:11,19 (i.e. revive, compare with שׁוּב 1 Kings 17:21f.), hence
> figurative refresh, cheer, 1 Kings 17:16; Psalm 19:8; Proverbs 25:14;
> Ruth 4:15; ׳שׁובב נ Psalm 23:3; ׳מַחְמַל נ your souls' compassion
> Ezekiel 24:21; ׳קצרה נ soul was impatient Numbers 21:4 (E), Judges
> 10:16; Judges 16:16; Zechariah 11:8; כי ׳אאריך נ that I should prolong
> my patience Job 6:11 הגר ׳ידעתם אתנֿ ye know the feeling of the
> stranger Exodus 23:9 (RD).

**CONCLUSION**

Lev 26:30 - "my soul will abhor you" is Hebrew idiom for the extreme disgust God has for idol worship.